# subspace of a lindelof space

Tags: general-topology

Define topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$,$\mathbb{R}\setminus\{2\}$, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2\}$, $\mathbb{R}$ are open sets in topology where $\mathbb{R}$ is real line.

Is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ Lindelöf in subspace topology?

Since topology contains finite number of open sets then space is compact, hence Lindelöf.
But I cannot understand why each singleton in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open.

Comment: I don't understand the notation. What does $R\{1\}$ mean? Are those four sets (whatever they are) the *only* open sets? Isn't the empty set open?

Comment: R{1} means R\{1}

Comment: these are only open sets

Comment: Then you don't have a topology, because the definition of a topology requires the empty set $\emptyset$ to be open.

Comment: What gave you the idea that each singleton in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is open?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $X$ has a finite topology. So $X$ and all its subspaces are even compact, not just Lindelöf.

In this topology iit's *not* the case that all singletons in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open. If that is claimed, the topology must be different : maybe the included point topology wrt $0$?

Or maybe you mean $\mathbb{R}$ in the excluded point topology wrt $0$? The topology is $\{\mathbb{R}\} \cup \{O \subseteq \mathbb{R}: 0 \notin O\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is compact while all singletons of $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ are open  ( as $\{x\}$ is open if $x\neq 0$) and so $A$ is not Lindelöf in the subspace topology.